# First-born in a case of two wives

Tags: ki-teitzei, bechor-firstborn, estates-inheritance

In the beginning of parshas כי תצא ([Devarim 21:15-17](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Deuteronomy.21.15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)), the Torah commands that in a case of one man having two wives who both bear him sons - that the first-born, even if it is from the wife he loves less, should be given the בכורה.

> כִּי־תִהְיֶיןָ לְאִישׁ שְׁתֵּי נָשִׁים הָאַחַת אֲהוּבָה וְהָאַחַת שְׂנוּאָה וְיָלְדוּ־לוֹ בָנִים הָאֲהוּבָה וְהַשְּׂנוּאָה וְהָיָה הַבֵּן הַבְּכֹר לַשְּׂנִיאָה׃
> וְהָיָה בְּיוֹם הַנְחִילוֹ אֶת־בָּנָיו אֵת אֲשֶׁר־יִהְיֶה לוֹ לֹא יוּכַל לְבַכֵּר אֶת־בֶּן־הָאֲהוּבָה עַל־פְּנֵי בֶן־הַשְּׂנוּאָה הַבְּכֹר׃
> כִּי אֶת־הַבְּכֹר בֶּן־הַשְּׂנוּאָה יַכִּיר לָתֶת לוֹ פִּי שְׁנַיִם בְּכֹל אֲשֶׁר־יִמָּצֵא לוֹ כִּי־הוּא רֵאשִׁית אֹנוֹ לוֹ מִשְׁפַּט הַבְּכֹרָה׃

But in a case where the two wives are both pregnant at the same time, and the wife with whom a child was conceived second gives birth first - which son gets the בכורה; the one conceived first or the one born first?

I vaguely remember hearing (perhaps in the name of the גר"א?) that we learn from the words כי הוא ראשית אונו that the first-conceived child is the בכור even if he ends up being born second. I looked through both the Mishneh Torah hilchos nachalos, and the Shulchan Aruch choshen mishpat siman 277, but couldn't find any explicit psak in regard to this.

Comment: Also relevant with one wife in cases of IVF

Comment: @Heshy Or fraternal twins

Comment: @DoubleAA Is there a way of telling which of two fraternal twins was conceived first?

Comment: @JoelK Not that I know of, but then it's a safek and neither claims bechora. Same applies to most ivf cases, where multiple eggs are fertilized at a time after retrieval. Plus ראשית אונו doesn't mean conception really but something more like which particular sperm cell exited first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Netziv in [Ha'amek Davar to Devarim 21:15](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Haamek_Davar_on_Deuteronomy.21.15.1?lang=bi) points out that we follow the time of birth, not conception, and shows how this is derived from the verses here.

He also notes, parenthetically, a contrary tradition from Gra (that we would follow the time of conception) but writes that he doesn't believe it possible that Gra said such a thing.

(Also relevant is [Rashi to Bereishit 25:26](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Rashi_on_Genesis.25.26.1?lang=bi) which implies (in a much more *midrashic* context) that the first conceived has some type of claim to be the firstborn.)